# The minimal value of a particular measure of the absolute disjunctiveness of a real number

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Given a real number $x$ and an integer $d \geq 1$, let $f_d(x)$ denote the *smallest* positive integer $k$ (if it exists) such that for *any* integer $b \geq 2$ the initial $\left\lfloor b^{(k/d)n} \right\rfloor$ symbols of the base-$b$ representation of the fractional part of $x$ contain all $n$-symbol sequences, i.e. any sequence of length $n$ occurs as a contiguous subsequence (there are exactly $b^n$ such sequences), assuming that the alphabet is of size $b.$ Note that $f_d(x)$ may exist if and only if $x$ is [absolutely disjunctive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_sequence#Rich_numbers), but I am not sure that being absolutely disjunctive (or even absolutely normal) is a *sufficient* condition for the existence of $f_d(x).$

Let $r_d$ denote the *minimal* integer $m$ such that there exists a real number $x$ such that $f_d(x) = m.$

Questions: given an arbitrary $d$, is $r_d$ a well-defined, *specific* integer? If no, why? If yes, is it possible to estimate the lower/upper bounds for, say, $r_{10}$?